# typeof() parameter - how does it work?

Tags: c#, .net

In the Code below:

```
string GetName(Type type)    
{       
    return ((type)this.obj).Name;    
}    

void Run()    
{       
    string name = GetName(typeof(MyClass));    
}
```

Im getting a "The type or name space cannot be found (are you missing using a directive or assembly reference?)" error. What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Do you have the correct using at the top for the correct namespace?

Comment: `(type)(this.object).Name;` looks completely wrong - what does `Update` method try to do?

Comment: Its "((type)this.obj).Name", sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cast to an instance !

type is a instance of the Type class, if you want to cast to certain Type, use Generics

```
void GetName<T>() where T : IObjectWithName { return ((T)this.object).Name; }
```

then you can call

```
string name = GetName<MyClass>();
```

If that makes sens.

Comment: It introduces an extra interface that OP may not want if there was many different class with a Name property.

Comment: @Lemuel Adane : Then they just need to implement IObjectWithName. Maybe we can help you further if you explain what are you trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do like this, you need Reflection to do something like what you are asking for:

```
void Update(Type type)
{
    PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty("Name");
    string name = info.GetValue(info, null);
}
```